# Cannot use Advanced Rest Client with Letsencrypt Websites because throws: sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: lets-encrypt, advanced-rest-client

My domain is: http://dev.www.triunfamos.com

I use Advanced Rest Client ( https://install.advancedrestclient.com/install ) and try to call to mentioned domain

It produced this output:

```
The requested URL can't be reached
The service might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
140278599439040:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO sslv3 alert handshake failure:../../vendor/node/deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:802:
```

If I use this website: https://apitester.com/ to call to my URL it works fine

But with this one it fails too: https://client.restlet.com/ throwing the error:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

My web server is nginx 1.10.3 ubuntu 16 and certbot is 0.26.1

What is the problem which dont able to use Advanced Rest Client or any others? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved by the official forum: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/cannot-use-advanced-rest-client-with-letsencrypt-websites-because-throws-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure/88104

Resume:
ARC not use TLS 1.2 and for nginx 1.10.x the `ssl_ecdh_curve` sentence must be removed (if I use ARC) from nginx configuration.

For nginx 1.11 the `ssl_ecdh_curve` must set `auto`

In sites which has nginx 1.10 but is working ARC is due to are using cloudflare SSL

It is adviced to install TLS 1.3 for nginx 1.11